# Tangent and normal equation

Tags: calculus

Given the differential equation of a curve $$y''=6x^2-2$$   at $x=1, y'=2$ and  $y=3$ find the equation of tangent and normal at $x=1$, also the equation of the curve ?

Comment: Welcome to the community! It seems that this is a question from homework, and please show your try first :)

Comment: Does y"=6×^2_2 mean $y'' = 6x^2-2$?

Comment: Yes i mean that

Comment: @ManishKundu Well... No. Watch my answer

Comment: Abdallh, why did you use  linear algebra as a tag? Use calculus instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating twice, we get:

$\begin{cases}
y(x)=\frac{x^4}{2}-x^2+ax+b\\
y(1)=3\\
y'(1)=2
\end{cases}$

Thus, inserting $x=1$ in the first equation, and deriving, we obtain:

$\begin{cases}
3=-\frac{1}{2}+a+b\\
2=2-2+a
\end{cases}$

Which is equivalent to:

$\begin{cases}
a=2\\
b=\frac{3}{2}
\end{cases}$

Your curve has thus equation:

$y(x)=\frac{x^4}{2}-x^2+2x+\frac{3}{2}$

In order to obtain tangent and normal to the curve at the point $(1,3)$, you need only eq. (1-2) of the first system.
The tangent will have equation:

$y=m(x-x_0)+y_0=mx-m+3=2x+1$

The normal, instead:
$y=-\frac{1}{m}(x-x_0)+y_0=-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{7}{2}$